# How to get bootstrap grid system to fill out empty spaces while assigning layout sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 divs, the first 3 divs appear beside one another, but the fourth one has to appear below the 3. The problem is the third div is lengthier and the fourth div gets moved to the end of the third div and that is causing a lot of white space. How can I move the div upwards and still maintain bootstrap grid layouts?

I want to move the brown div up and fit it within the white space there. How can I achieve this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
      incididunt ut labore et doloreLorem

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:brown;">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<div class="row">` from

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:brown;">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
  </div>
</div>
```

It should look like this

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:brown;">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
  </div>
```

Comment: I can't use that match-height library because the height of that red div needs to be taller. I cannot make other divs smaller

Comment: Sorry, didn't run your code. I now understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

make line 29 look like this...

```
    <div class="row m-0">
```

Comment: The `m-*-*` utility class is specific to Bootstrap 4.x.  Based on the original post they are using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: In that case add css that says 'margin-top: 0 !important;'

Answer (score 0):

Use `container-fluid` wrapper div around row. 
row div must have a `container` or `container-fluid` div as a ancestor around them.

Also add `display: flex` to the first row and keep the 2nd row parallel to the first row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:pink;">
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et doloreLorem

</div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:brown;">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```